# Deploying ASP.NET MVC 5 app between IIS servers where kendo grid changes from GET to POST upon contacting Home Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis, deployment, kendo-grid

So I successfully deployed an MVC 5 web app and a REST Web Api 2 app on the local server using IIS.  Tried the same thing in a slightly different environment, and only 1 out of 2 deployed successfully.

The MVC 5 app deploys, but there's a weird JavaScript error on the Kendo UI grid.  The new environment forces my GET requests to become POST and then makes a complex object inside of the body.  I am truly at a loss for what could be causing this.  I actually saw something at the end of the day inside of jQuery where it picks the request verb ("GET"/"POST") based on the transport mechanism, idk, was grasping for straws and just logging every object in the console.

How does jQuery pick the default behavior?  It must key in on the production environment somehow, like inherit something.  I'll screen shot or provide more info if I think someone is heading in the right direction.  This problem is specific to Kendo UI grid, all 3 not working but other widgets are.  Code is the same on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment problems solved by myself.  It turns out when you do a "clean solution" in visual studio, it cleans that directory.  To clean a published web-app, which I clearly needed to do, you simply tell visual studio to delete the old stuff, time difference in compilation is not noticeable.

[image]